# What is mean by "Rnobody" in R script installation

Tags: r, cygwin

I currently working with a Java based jetty server setup which involves servlet and HTML. The objective is to **call R script from Java**

In one of the custom configuration properties file inside `WEB-INF/classes`, I have encountered a statement as follows.

```
RScriptLocation=/usr/local/bin/Rnobody
```

This property file is not related to jetty server, it is the developer who created this properties file for storing constants.

I have installed **R** from **cygwin** setup, but I could not locate that particular executable, I only see `/usr/bin/R`

what is **Rnobody** and how to install it

Comment: What "configuration properties file" are you talking about?

Comment: Did R also install `Rscript`? Because that seems like what it should be pointing to rather than `Rnobody` because `Rnobody` isn't really a thing. You'd probably be better off contacting the developer to see what the intention was.

Comment: `/usr/bin/Rscript.exe` is included in the R cygwin package